# Create a Segmented Control Widget with slider button - Flutter

Tags: flutter, button, flutter-layout, controls, segment

How do I create something similar to this?:

Demo :
[image: Demo]

I know flutter has

```
CupertinoSegmentedControl()
```

But this creates something similar to tabs, nothing that slides like something a Switch with a button inside.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

Best thing I have found is the `CupertinoSlidingSegmentedControl()`:

```
class _ViewState extends State<View> {
  int segmentedControlGroupValue = 0;
  final Map<int, Widget> myTabs = const <int, Widget>{
    0: Text("Item 1"),
    1: Text("Item 2")
  };

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: CupertinoSlidingSegmentedControl(
          groupValue: segmentedControlGroupValue,
          children: myTabs,
          onValueChanged: (i) {
            setState(() {
              segmentedControlGroupValue = i;
            });
          }),
    );
  }
}
```

Hope this helps. See the docs [here](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/cupertino/CupertinoSlidingSegmentedControl-class.html).

Comment: Great, here the ticket about the implementation and a image showing the behavior.
https://github.com/flutter/flutter/pull/42775

Answer (score 2):

Check out the package https://pub.dev/packages/material_segmented_control for controls like [image]

Also check out https://pub.dev/packages/custom_sliding_segmented_control for these kinds of controls

[image]

Both of them let you customize visual aspects of the control like corner radius, color, etc. Personally I'm using them because `CupertinoSegmentedControl` and `CupertinoSlidingSegmentedControl` don't allow for changing the corner radius, which I needed for an app.

Kudos to the writers!

Answer (score 1):

Duo to material 3 without any package and easily you can use `SegmentedButton`:

```dart
SegmentedButton<String>(
  segments: const <ButtonSegment<String>>[
    ButtonSegment<String>(
        value: 'day',
        label: Text('Day'),
        icon: Icon(Icons.calendar_view_day)),
    ButtonSegment<String>(
        value: 'week',
        label: Text('Week'),
        icon: Icon(Icons.calendar_view_week)),
    ButtonSegment<String>(
        value: 'month',
        label: Text('Month'),
        icon: Icon(Icons.calendar_view_month)),
    ButtonSegment<String>(
        value: 'year',
        label: Text('Year'),
        icon: Icon(Icons.calendar_today)),
  ],
  selected: <String>{'day'},
  onSelectionChanged: (Set<String> newSelection) {},
),
```

For more info read this document: https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/SegmentedButton-class.html