# dart generic typedef function is not subtype of error with CupertinoSlidingSegmentedControl

Tags: flutter, dart

**Context:**

I'm trying to extend and implement a custom [CupertinoSlidingSegmentedControl](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/cupertino/CupertinoSlidingSegmentedControl-class.html) with some alterations.

Here is a great example of using the widget:

```
class _ViewState extends State<View> {
  int segmentedControlGroupValue = 0;
  final Map<int, Widget> myTabs = const <int, Widget>{
    0: Text("Item 1"),
    1: Text("Item 2")
  };

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: CupertinoSlidingSegmentedControl(
          groupValue: segmentedControlGroupValue,
          children: myTabs,
          onValueChanged: (i) {
            setState(() {
              segmentedControlGroupValue = i;
            });
          }),
    );
  }
}
```

from [@AidanMarshall](https://stackoverflow.com/users/10193563/aidan-marshall)'s answer found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60480668/4628115)

**What am I trying to do?**

I am customizing the myTabs into a custom [itemBuilder](https://flutter.dev/docs/cookbook/lists/mixed-list#2-convert-the-data-source-into-a-list-of-widgets) similarly to the [ListView.builder](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/ListView-class.html) implementation. My implementation should be used as follows:

```
SegmentedSlider<GenderPreference>(
  values: GenderPreference.values,
  thumbColor: Colors.blue, // or use a custom theme
  onValueChanged: (value) {
    // update profile information here
  },
  sliderItemBuilderFunction: (context, item, active) {
    return Text(
      GenderPreference.asString(item),
      style: Theme.of(context).textTheme.subtitle2!.copyWith(
        color: active
            ? Colors.white
            : Colors.green,
      ),
    );
  },
  selectedValue: GenderPreference.None,
)
```

With this, I am using my own `sliderItemBuilderFunction` function defined as follows:

```
typedef Widget ItemValueWidgetBuilder<T>(BuildContext context, T item, bool active);
```

*this accepts the build `context`, the generic item `T` and a (is) `active` convenience field*

**Problem:**

The problem is each time I run the widget, I get the following error for each item in `values`:

```
======== Exception caught by widgets library =======================================================
The following _TypeError was thrown building SegmentedSlider<GenderPreference>(dirty, dependencies: [_LocalizationsScope-[GlobalKey#0a25e], _InheritedTheme], state: _SegmentedSliderState<GenderPreference>#40901):
type '(BuildContext, GenderPreference, bool) => Text' is not a subtype of type '(BuildContext, dynamic, bool) => Widget'

The relevant error-causing widget was: 
  SegmentedSlider<GenderPreference> file:///C:/Users/CybeX/MyAwesomeApp/awesome-app-mobile-flutter/lib/viewcontrollers/profile/ui_profile.dart:309:20
When the exception was thrown, this was the stack: 
#0      _SegmentedSliderState.build.<anonymous closure> (package:cozy_up/framework/ui/components/slider.dart:34:28)
#1      MappedListIterable.elementAt (dart:_internal/iterable.dart:412:31)
#2      ListIterator.moveNext (dart:_internal/iterable.dart:341:26)
#3      new _GrowableList._ofEfficientLengthIterable (dart:core-patch/growable_array.dart:188:27)
#4      new _GrowableList.of (dart:core-patch/growable_array.dart:150:28)
...
====================================================================================================
Reloaded 0 libraries in 1 536ms.
```

**Question:**

```
'(BuildContext, GenderPreference, bool) => Text' is not a subtype of type '(BuildContext, dynamic, bool) => Widget'
```

Firstly, the `'(BuildContext, GenderPreference, bool) => Text'` is my custom function, which should return a `Widget` as specified in the typedef.

**Force Widget inside Slider's build function?**

If I force this as a `Widget` with

`Widget _widget = widget.sliderItemBuilderFunction(context, e, e == activeValue);`

in my slider `build` function, I get exactly the same error.

**Force Widget inside itemBuilder's function?**

Further, if I return a Widget in my `sliderItemBuilderFunction()` implementation, I get the same error, but

```
'(BuildContext, GenderPreference, bool) => Widget' is not a subtype of type '(BuildContext, dynamic, bool) => Widget'
```

**What am I doing wrong?**

---

**Enum Used**

```
enum GenderPreference {
  Male,
  Female,
  Other,
  None,
}

extension GenderPreferenceExt on GenderPreference {
  static const enums = {
    GenderPreference.Male: 'Male',
    GenderPreference.Female: 'Female',
    GenderPreference.Other: 'Other',
    GenderPreference.None: 'None',
  };

  static String asString(GenderPreference genderPreference) {
    return enums[genderPreference] ?? "";
  }

  static GenderPreference parse(String _mode) {
    if (_mode == "" || _mode == null) {
      return GenderPreference.None;
    }
    return enums.entries
        .where((element) => element.value.toLowerCase() == _mode.toLowerCase())
        .first
        .key;
  }
}
```

**Full Slider Implementation:**

```
import 'package:flutter/cupertino.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

typedef Widget ItemValueWidgetBuilder<T>(
    BuildContext context, T item, bool active);

class SegmentedSlider<T> extends StatefulWidget {
  final Color backgroundColor;
  final Color thumbColor;
  final ValueChanged<T?> onValueChanged;
  final T selectedValue;
  final List<T> values;
  final ItemValueWidgetBuilder<T> sliderItemBuilderFunction;

  const SegmentedSlider(
      {Key? key,
      this.thumbColor = Colors.grey,
      this.backgroundColor = Colors.white,
      required this.onValueChanged,
      required this.sliderItemBuilderFunction,
      required this.selectedValue,
      required this.values})
      : super(key: key);

  @override
  _SegmentedSliderState<T> createState() => new _SegmentedSliderState<T>();
}

class _SegmentedSliderState<T> extends State<SegmentedSlider> {
  late T activeValue;

  @override
  void initState() {
    // TODO: implement initState
    super.initState();
    activeValue = widget.selectedValue;
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    List<MapEntry<T, Widget>> map = widget.values.map((e) {
      var _widget =
          widget.sliderItemBuilderFunction(context, e, e == activeValue);
      print(_widget);
      return MapEntry<T, Widget>(e, Container());
    }).toList();
    Map<T, Widget> children = Map.fromEntries(map);

    return CupertinoSlidingSegmentedControl<T>(
      backgroundColor: widget.backgroundColor,
      thumbColor: widget.thumbColor,
      onValueChanged: (value) {
        activeValue = value!;
        widget.onValueChanged(value);
      },
      children: children,
      groupValue: widget.selectedValue,
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The essential problem is that `_SegmentedSliderState` does not automatically know how to parameterize the type of its parent widget, so the inherited `widget` property has the type `SegmentedSlider<dynamic>` instead of `SegmentedSlider<T>`.

To fix this, just declare your class like so:

```
class _SegmentedSliderState<T> extends State<SegmentedSlider<T>> {
                                                            ^^^
```

Comment: *facepalm, how did I miss that...thank you!

Comment: After several days of digging the internet. THAT SAVED MY LIFE!